# jQuery ajax timeout function?

Tags: jquery

I make a GET request with ajax and expect a JSON value to be returned.

However, my hosting has a firewall installed. It only takes 2 requests per second, otherwise blocks the connection and shows an error page. (a blank page.) So if I make 3 requests in a second, third request never retrieve the JSON response. Hence, loading.gif keeps turning and turning.

How can I make a timeout in jQuery, let's say 5 seconds, so it'll callback the timeout function?

Comment: `$.ajax` accepts a `timeout` option. You can then test in the error handler what the cause for the error was (e.g. the timeout). Please have a look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: YourUrl,
    async: true,
    timeout: 5000,       //5 seconds
    success: function(args) { 

                     // on success code
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom GET request with timeout function as a parameter:

```
$.getWithTimeOut = function(url, params, datatype, onsuccessfunction, aftertimeoutfunction, timeout){
     $.get(url, params, function(data) {
          onsuccessfunction(data);
          setTimeout(aftertimeoutfunction, timeout);
     }, datatype);
};
```

Then you just call:

```
$.getWithTimeOut('url/url', { param1: value1 }, 'json', function(data){
     //success code here
}, function(/*params*/){
   //timeout code here
}, 5000);
```